# AJAX: sending xmlhttp requests in a loop

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have this function below and I call that function in a loop I get the alert n times but only n-1 or sometimes n-2 responses

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        //document.getElementById("warnings_panel").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

alert("in ajax) 

xmlhttp.open("GET","getresponse.php?start="+ start + "&end=" + end,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: How do you call this function? What does your loop look like? BTW, you miss a `"` after `"in ajax`, but I assume that's merely a copy-paste mistake, otherwise it wouldn't run at all. BTW, always properly encode your query parameters (variables `start` and `end`) using `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: oh yes !! sorry for that ... this function is called inside the for loop for other function ... thank you for your effort ... I would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: Yes, but show it in your code above.

Comment: @Marcel .. the whole code is too big to put in here .... basically it is like this .... there is this function say function abc() .... it does some proessing in order to determine whether it should call this function or not and if condition is satisfied then it is called ... and this is done in a loop ..... also I know that the correct parameters enter in this function because after posting this question here I did try putting an alert in the start of this function and it gives the correct values ... only problem is receiving responses .... hope that helps

Comment: No, this isn't helpful at all. You really should show *relevant* parts of your code: show the loop, show how this function is called.

Comment: Believe me the code is about 200 lines and thats why I cannon post it here otherwise I would .. I am really sorry for that

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints: “Be as short as possible. If I have to wade through hundreds of lines of code to find the problem, I'm doing work that *you* should be doing. Often if you work hard to reduce the problem to a short but complete program, you'll find the issue yourself.”

Answer (score 1):

I have made a class (that you can modify easily) for calling a function in loop and it calls the functions correctly. Maybe this could apply to your need.

(Also if anyone sees something wrong it's good to hear from others)

**test.htm**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myXmlHttp() { 

    /*constructor simulator*/ 
    this.setPersitent=
    function (file, onReadyFunc,params,loop) 
    {  
        myXmlHttpObj.loop = loop;  
        myXmlHttpObj.file=file;
        myXmlHttpObj.onReadyFunc='myXmlHttpObj.'+onReadyFunc;
        myXmlHttpObj.params=params;  
        myXmlHttpObj.mySetRequest();    
    }
    this.setParams=
    function ( params ) 
    {   
        myXmlHttpObj.params=params;  
    }

    <!--Standard initial code-->
    this.mySetRequest =
    function  ()
    {
        request = false;
        try { request = new XMLHttpRequest(); } 
        catch (trymicrosoft) {
            try { request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } 
            catch (othermicrosoft) {
                try {request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} 
                catch (failed) {request = false;}/*catch3*/}/*catch2*/}/*catch1*/
        if (!request) 
        alert("Error initializing XMLHttpRequest!"); 
    }  /*func*/ 

    this.mySendReq=
    function() 
    { 
        var url = myXmlHttpObj.file;   
        request.open("POST", url, true);  
        //Some http headers must be set along with any POST request.
        request.setRequestHeader
        ("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", myXmlHttpObj.params.length);
        request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 
        request.onreadystatechange = eval(myXmlHttpObj.onReadyFunc);  
        request.send(myXmlHttpObj.params);  
    } 

    this.listenPHP = 
   function  ( ) {    
     if ( request.readyState == 4) {
       if ( request.status == 200) 
       {   
            alert(request.responseText);
            myXmlHttpObj.loop--;
            if(myXmlHttpObj.loop>0)
            { 
                myXmlHttpObj.setParams("js_rand="+Math.random()+"");
                myXmlHttpObj.mySendReq();  
            }

        }//inner if 
       else{alert("status is " + request.status);}
     }//outer iff
   }//function  

}//END 

myXmlHttpObj = new myXmlHttp();
myXmlHttpObj.setPersitent
('getresponse.php', 'listenPHP',"js_rand="+Math.random()+"",3)  ;

myXmlHttpObj.mySendReq();  

</script>
</head>
<body >

</body>
</html>
```

and **getresponse.php**

```
<?PHP
echo 'I recived this random from js:',$_POST['js_rand'],'
 this rand is from php:',rand(1,9999);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>`onreadystatechange` gets terminated when your function ends because the `xmlhttp` object gets removed as it is not a global variable. Am I right?</s>

Better would be to put only the AJAX request in a function, so that the `xmlhttp` object is only created once (I used a shorter version to create the `xmlhttp` object in this example).

```
var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

function request() {
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getresponse.php?start=' + start + '&end=' + end, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: I have declared the xmlhttp variable above the function so I think that is not the problem .... From what I have heard the problem here is my new response overwrites the previous one .. I donot know how to overcome it yet ... thanks for the effort though

Comment: Re your first statement: **no**, you're not right. This is where closures pop in: the JavaScript engine knows it can't throw away the value of `xmlhttp` when the function ends, so it's kept alive until it's no longer needed.

Comment: You shouldn't reuse the same `xmlhttp` each time; it's better to create a new one using a local variable. Now, each time the function is called and `xmlhttp.open` is executed, a possible pending request will be canceled.

Comment: Then what you have to do is create a new AJAX object if AJAX object 1 is busy. That is the basic idea, I don't know exactly how it's done, but I'm sure there are tutorials about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are *many* bad tutorials out there, that create global variables and the like, which might cause troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this should work, but we need more information about how you actually run that loop to know what might be wrong.

I also added `encodeURIComponent` and changed the condition inside the callback function, because `status` isn't always `200` when `readyState` reaches `4`.

```
function request(start, end) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getresponse.php?start=' + encodeURIComponent(start) + '&end=' + encodeURIComponent(end), true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            } else {
                // status ≠ 200, output useful error message
            }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```