# HTML / AJAX / PHP synchronous harmony? Could asynchronous ever work?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, synchronous

I've been working out the best way to bridge javascript to get data from php with Ajax.
And all while trying to keep the lines of code to a minimum and with greatest speed.
I've come up with a way to pass AJAX a value by Object so it can be altered as if it was passed by reference and then send it back. But so far, I can only do this synchronous as the data will not be available until AJAX completes.

Point is:
I've been looking for an easy way access all of my PHP content with javascript.
Build a simple javascript(GetSomePHPstuff) API  if you will.

As I am a novice at web programming, I would love to hear some input and feedback on this.
This is what I have come up with.

**In this example, I am sending a text value from html through javascript to ajax to php and php sends it back to ajax back to javascript back to my html page.**

Here is our simple HTML type file.

**TEST.html**

```
<script language="javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Return Text" 
onClick="alert(ajaxReturnText(document.getElementById('text').value));"/>
```

Here is the ajax/javascript file.

**AJAX.js**

```
function ReturnText(input, output){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            output.value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","php.php?text="+input,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function ajaxReturnText(input){
    var output = new Object();
    ReturnText(input, output);
    return output.value
}
```

And here is the PHP file

**php.php**

```
<?php 
function ReturnText($text){
    return $text;
}
if($text = $_GET["text"]){
    echo ReturnText($text);
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Sir/madam, have you heard of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: First of all I suggest you use a JavaScript Library to avoid having to write so much "per-browser" code. That's something that has been solved by several JS Frameworks.

Comment: Without using another library, how can we make this code work asynchronously.

Comment: @Blender Thank you for the hint. I will look into jQuery.

Comment: If you want to be able to call `ajaxReturnText()` like any other function that returns a value then you'll have to stick with synchronous Ajax calls. There are ways to refactor code to instead work with callbacks from asynch Ajax, which can work nicely in some cases but gets messy in others. Either way I agree with the others about using a library to do the actual Ajax calls for you. (By the way, "I'd like feedback" is not the sort of "question" that Stack Overflow is intended to host.)

Comment: I guess what i'm asking.   Is there a way to make this code any shorter and/or faster?

Comment: I wrote a little thing for this that is wicked fast and transports data using jQuery/PHP that might be very close to what you need. And yes, another vote for jQuery. https://github.com/fabld/Wormhole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work asynchronously this way. You have to understand that this line:

```
output.value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

is going to be executed after ajaxReturnText() is done if you define it asynchronously. If you defined synchronously then ajaxreturtext() will not proceed until the request is done. To me your problem is that the code must respect the foundamental rules, in your case this is that you have to remember to define what to do after ajax inside this the "update function here:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            output.value = xmlhttp.responseText;
/*define what to do next here*/
        }
```

So you never call code to be executed asynch directly but insted you call it from inside the proper function, see complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/*to be called synch*/
function ReturnText(input){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ 
            /*here define what to be called asynch*/
            ajaxReturnText(xmlhttp.responseText); 
        }
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","php.php?text="+input,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

/*to be called asynch*/
function ajaxReturnText(input){
    var output = new Object();
    output.value =input; 
    alert(output.value);
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=
     "This is the value of the object: "+input;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Return Text" 
onClick="ReturnText(document.getElementById('text').value);"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to experience more I have a class for it: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091275/ajax-sending-xmlhttp-requests-in-a-loop/7740522#7740522)

Answer (score 1):

You can receive server-generated events asynchronously in realtime without any problem, I did it long time ago before any AJAX. Now this way called [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). I used frames and script techniques. Now it's better to do with ajax, but here some problems you have to solve.

You can receive data in realtime using .onreadystatechange callback with `.readyState==3`.
 This callback generated every time when new data come from server. You need to remember last `.responseText` size and read new data from this point to end, then store new size.

- **Problem number one**:
  IE generate exception when you try to read `.responseText` before event with `.readyState==4`. So server part must drop connection after every event to make readyState readable and force client recreate it again (see 'long polling'). If browser is not IE you don't need to recreate connection every time. But here we face problem number too.
- **Problem number two:**
  `.responseText` size. It can be very big if connection used for long time. So you need to implement (events or bytes send) counter on server or client and recreate connection by counter overflow.
- **One more problem** - timeouts. You need to disable timeout on server (see `set_time_limit()`) and send something insignificant (space forexample) to browser when you have no events to prevent browser timeout.

Usually you need two channels to server: upload and download. You have upload channel with jQuery or another framework but I don't sure about download. I afraid you can't use `readyState==3` technique with jQuery. May be [APE Framework](http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Main) can do it?